# How to use email address as JID to login Openfire with custom database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openfire

I had used the XMPPFramework for IOS to connect the local Openfire server, and It's successful. When I change the normal JID to a email address like `xxx@xxx.xxx@127.0.0.1`

It's failed. I'm considering that escape the NSString.

Escaped String: `xxx\40xxx.xxx@127.0.0.1`

In my custom database, the loginEmail Field is `'xxx@xxx.xxx'`.

So AppDelegate: xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:

Comment: The quesion is very clear. How to use email as username to login?

Comment: I'd love to answer your question, but I can't because the individuals who closed your topic apparently didn't understand your question.  I'm dealing with a very similar problem and while I don't have a perfect solution, I have a general answer I'd love to post.  META SO: WTF are all the question nazi's out enmasse these days.

Comment: @Stony The question also **specifies**: email address like `xxx@xxx.xxx@127.0.0.1`. AFAIK that's not a valid email address. So, hm, not that clear - is it really an email address that the OP intends to use?... But OK, answers waiting, I'll support that re-open vote...

Comment: @DanCornilescu - the OP talking about a JID using an email address as a username.  It's not an email address.  This is specifically the issue I have with mods closing topics to which they are not experts on (like any of us are experts at anything, really).  Quite frankly, folks looked at it and were too ignorant to know that it was a legitimate question.  I'd have love to have stumbled across this and found some 2 year old discussion.  But alas.

Comment: Email cant be used as jid... If you want to maintain db, you should use it something like this user_id@127.0.0.1, I mean that you should use user ID to make it specific, it will be something like 25@127.0.0.1 and it is valid jid.